# How to use matrix as a condition in an if statement in a GitHub Action

Tags: github-actions

I often use matrices in Github Actions to simplify my iterations.

For example, here's a matrix that works fine.

---------- Lint ----------

```
  terraform-lint:
    Strategy:
      matrix:
        working_dir: ['./AA/sandbox', './BB/dev', './CC/global', './DD/dev', './EE/prod']
    if: github.ref_name != 'main' && github.base_ref != 'main'
    uses: ./.github/workflows/terraform-lint.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      working_dir: ${{ matrix.working_dir }}
```

I want to use a loop like below, but the if's condition has `${{ matrix.project }}` doesn't seem to work.

The error message is as follows.

- `Unrecognized named-value: 'matrix'. Located at position 1 within expression: matrix.project`

---------- Apply ----------

```
  terraform-apply-cloudrnd:
    Strategy:
      Matrix:
        include:
          - project: "AA"
            working_dir: "AA/sandbox" 
          - project: "BB"
            working_dir: "BB/dev" 
          - project: "CC"
            working_dir: "CC/global" 
          - project: "DD"
            working_dir: "DD/dev" 
          - project: "EE"
            working_dir: "EE/prod"                                     
    if: |
      (github.ref_name == 'main' || github.base_ref == 'main') &&
      (needs.changes.outputs.${{ matrix.project }} == 'true')
    needs: [changes]
    uses: ./.github/workflows/terraform-apply.yml
    secrets:
      GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT_AUTOMATION }}
      GH_USERNAME: ${{ vars.GH_USERNAME_AUTOMATION }}
    with:
      deployment_dir: ${{ matrix.working_dir }}
```

`needs.changes.outputs.AA` uses `dorny/paths-filter@v2` to detect changes to AA-related code inside the repository.

I have multiple projects and want to iterate through them with a script that does an apply.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

So far, job-level if conditions do not accept matrix values because they are processed before the matrix.

[Unrecognized named-value: 'matrix' in job if conditional](https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/1985)

As a workaround, you could add a precursor job that does it. This is untested code, but the principle is clear. Some filtering method has to be used prior to the conditional job.

```
prepare:
  if: github.ref_name == 'main' || github.base_ref == 'main'
  needs: [changes]
  outputs:
    working_dirs: ${{ steps.filtered.outputs.json }}
  steps:
    - name: set up matrix
      id: matrix
      uses: nickofthyme/object-remap@v2.0.0
      with:
        AA: '${{ needs.changes.outputs.AA }}: {"AA/sandbox"}'
        BB: '${{ needs.changes.outputs.BB }}: {"BB/dev"}'
        CC: '${{ needs.changes.outputs.CC }}: {"CC/global"}'
        DD: '${{ needs.changes.outputs.DD }}: {"DD/dev"}'
        EE: '${{ needs.changes.outputs.EE }}: {"EE/prod"}'
    - name: filter matrix
      id: filtered
      uses: nickofthyme/object-remap@v2.0.0
      with:
        working_dir: ${{ fromJson(steps.matrix.outputs.json).*.true }}

terraform-apply-cloudrnd:
  strategy:
    matrix: ${{ fromJson(needs.prepare.outputs.working_dirs) }}
  needs: [prepare]
  uses: ./.github/workflows/terraform-apply.yml # access matrix.working_dir
```